# Formatting DynamoDB data to normal JSON in Typescript and AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, unmarshalling

I am retrieving data from DynamoDB using a query and I get the following returned:

`[{"serviceUserId":{"S":"123456789"},"createdDate":{"S":"11-12-2021"}}]`

The DynamoDB JSON format has the type in in which I am trying to get rid of by converting to a normal JSON format. I have tried using the `AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall` but I am getting an error in my code:

```
Argument of type 'ItemList' is not assignable to parameter of type "AttributeMap".
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type "AttributeMap[]".
```

Here is my code:

```
                 if (result.Count > 0) {
                     const newImage = AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(
                        result.Items
                         )
                   console.log('new Image: ' + JSON.stringify(newImage));
                    resolve(newImage);
                 } else { 
                     console.log('No record found');
                     reject(err);
                 }
```

If I remove the [] brackets in the DynamoDB JSON then it is converted successfully, but obviously I cannot do this in my program as the brackets are there for a reason!

Does anyone know how to convert my JSON file to a format that `unmarshall` will accept?

Comment: What is the value of `result`? What is `result.Items`?

Comment: result and result.items is '[object Object]' and when I stringify it I get '[{"serviceUserId":{"S":"123456789"},"createdDate":{"S":"11-12-2021"}}]'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Map through the items and unmarshal one by one.  `(un)marshal` [accepts an object type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html#unmarshall-1), not an array.

```js
import { marshall, unmarshall } from '@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb';  // SDK V3, but worked the same in V2

(() => {
  const items = [{ serviceUserId: { S: '123456789' }, createdDate: { S: '11-12-2021' } }];
  
  // from DynamoDB JSON
  const unmarshalled = items.map((i) => unmarshall(i));

  // make the return trip back to DynamoDB JSON
  const marshalled = unmarshalled.map((i) => marshall(i));
})();
```

Comment: Thanks - I shall give it a test a bit later but it all seems to make sense so hopefully it will work!

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't quite work as my items variable has strings: '[{"serviceUserId":{"S":"123456789"},"createdDate":{"S":"11-12-2021"}}]' and yours was an object: 'const items = [{ serviceUserId: { S: '123456789' }, createdDate: { S: '11-12-2021' } }];' Unmarshall does not accept strings.

Comment: In addition, the DynamoDB data could have multiple items returned: '[{"serviceUserId":{"S":"123456789"},"createdDate":{"S":"11-12-2021"}},{"serviceUserId":{"S":"123456790"},"createdDate":{"S":"11-12-2021"},{"serviceUserId":{"S":"123456791"},"createdDate":{"S":"11-12-2021"}}]'

Comment: Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Convert your string into JSON with `JSON.parse`.  Parsing will fail, however, if the string is not proper JSON.  The multiple items string in your comment won't parse because the second element is missing a closing bracket.  The answer will handle an array of items.  That's what [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does.

Comment: Great - that worked. I have parsed it first and now I the type in the Dynamodb JSON has been removed. Many thanks!